# StorageServiceAccountSample application reports "KeyStore JKS implementation not found"

Tags: android, google-api-java-client

The very first line of [StorageServiceAccountSample](http://samples.google-api-java-client.googlecode.com/hg/storage-serviceaccount-cmdline-sample/instructions.html)

```
HTTP_TRANSPORT = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
```

causes the "KeyStore JKS implementation not found":

```
W/System.err(20142): java.security.KeyStoreException: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: KeyStore JKS implementation not found
W/System.err(20142):    at java.security.KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.java:119)
W/System.err(20142):    at com.google.api.client.util.SecurityUtils.getJavaKeyStore(SecurityUtils.java:48)
W/System.err(20142):    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.GoogleUtils.getCertificateTrustStore(GoogleUtils.java:74)
W/System.err(20142):    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.javanet.GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport(GoogleNetHttpTransport.java:55)
```

As I read Android doesn't support JKS, how should I modify this method to work around it?

Answer (score 10):

Replaced

```
HTTP_TRANSPORT = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
```

with

```
HTTP_TRANSPORT = AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport();
```

and the problem went away.

Comment: For those who follow this route, `AndroidHttp` class is in the `com.google.api.client.extensions.android.http` package. Not `com.google.api.client.extensions.android2.AndroidHttp`, which is deprecated

Comment: Yes the first _GoogleNetHttpTransport_ works fine for Java (or non-android Test) and the second _AndroidHttp_ is required when running on Android. 
This is packaged as an extension of the Google API Client for Android. 
In my case : **implementation 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.25.0'**

Answer (score 2):

I've found an answer on [google issue tracker.](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/robovm/7WYEE5ASpns/nxKmfNoz2lEJ)

Replace

```
HTTP_TRANSPORT = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
```

with

```
HTTP_TRANSPORT = new com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport()
```

But don't know, how it's working.

Comment: @Martijin Pieters Tell me How could it be identical answer? see the Jerry's answer. It's totally different from my answer.(compare code snippet) Watch carefully before deleting the answer. That's why I'm posting the same answer again.