# NoSuchAlgorithmException with KeyStore.getInstance in android application

Tags: java, android, ssl

I write program in android for communication with server, I use SSL protocol, when I write this code

```
 KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance( "JKS" );
```

I get this error

> java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: KeyStore JKS implementation
>   not found

How can I resolve my problem? 
My Algorithm is JKS.

Best Regards

Comment: [Came across this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18882825/681929)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Android does not support JKS keystore. However you can convert your JKS keystore to BouncyCastle BKS keystore and it will work.

@edit

You will need bcprov-jdk16-145.jar

```
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore mytruststore.jks -destkeystore mytruststore.bks -srcstoretype JKS -deststoretype BKS -srcstorepass changeit -deststorepass changeit -provider org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider
```

If your bcprov jar is in another directory add -providerpath path.

code taken from: http://www.knowledgebit.appspot.com/zahangirbd/TopicView.action;jsessionid=E2BZt_6bp4uFFbMyq42gWg?id=56001

Comment: can you told, how can i convert JKS keystore to BouncyCastle? , thank you

Comment: In our client program?

Comment: Convert JKS->BKS using keytool and add your new .bks keystore to res/raw folder and use it to initialize KeyStore

Comment: thank you, i write client application, i have to change this solution myself or person that write server program?

Comment: Do you have that .jks keystore? If yes, do It yourself, if no how do you know that you want to use jks keystore?

Comment: thank you, i have .jks, i put "bcprov-jdk16-1.45" in "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0\lib" but i can not change jks to bks i get this error: "java.lang.classnotfoundexception org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.bouncycastleprovider" ,how can i resolve my problem?

Comment: Add –providerpath with path to your bcprov file

Comment: Thank you, please explain more. providerpath ?

Comment: In your case add -providerpath C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0\lib\bcprov-jdk16-1.45 to command converting keystores.

Comment: Thank you, but i do not understand your mean, Add to yhis command"keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore mytruststore.jks -destkeystore mytruststore.bks -srcstoretype JKS -deststoretype BKS -srcstorepass changeit -deststorepass changeit -provider org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider "  ؟