# KeyStore MRTD implementation not found

Tags: android

I´m trying to get data from NFC in Android but in the data capture moment I have this error:

**Caused by: java.security.KeyStoreException: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: KeyStore MRTD implementation not found**

I put my code here:

```
private var m_ksUserDNIe: KeyStore? = null

 fun loadDGs() {

        // Leemos los certificados
        try {

            runOnUiThread {

                buttonOK.text = "Leyendo..."

                // Crash Here!
                m_ksUser = KeyStore.getInstance("MRTD")
                m_ksUser?.load(null, null)

                println("ASA")

                m_ksUser?.getKey(AUTH_CERT_ALIAS, null)
                m_ksUser?.getCertificate(AUTH_CERT_ALIAS)?.encoded
            }

        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
            throw e
        }
}
```

Anyone has any idea?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Have a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24033346/nosuchalgorithmexception-with-keystore-getinstance-in-android-application) Hope, it helps

Comment: I read this, but I dont understand this part:

**keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore mytruststore.jks -destkeystore mytruststore.bks -srcstoretype JKS -deststoretype BKS -srcstorepass changeit -deststorepass changeit -provider org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider.**

I´ve tried to import this dependency with Open module settings and click in + searching the jar file, previously donwloaded.