# Google analytics api v3 in android application

Tags: android

I am trying to get Google analytic data in my application using `analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3`, but the problem is I'm stuck on some step.

`com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport` is not working at all. It throws an exception:

```
java.security.KeyStoreException: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: 
KeyStore JKS implementation not found
```

But I'm not able to understand how to modify this code for Android.

Is it possible to fetch the Google analytic data in an Android application?

Answer (score -1):

check [[this]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18862779/storageserviceaccountsample-application-reports-keystore-jks-implementation-not) link. It may help you.

Replace

```
HTTP_TRANSPORT = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
```

with

```
HTTP_TRANSPORT = AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport();
```

and the problem went away.

Comment: thanx @DalmTO. I will take care next time.

Comment: I am writing this code... 

code:
public static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY=GsonFactory.getDefaultInstance();

this code is not showing any error but while Gradle compiling it is given errors
Error:(49, 65) error: cannot find symbol method getDefaultInstance()
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.