# Google Books API - KeyStore JKS implementation not found

Tags: java, android, google-books

I'm trying to use Google Book API. However i keep getting the error :

"KeyStore JKS Implementation not found"

The code is taken directly from Google Books API Sample and (According to [StorageServiceAccountSample application reports "KeyStore JKS implementation not found"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18862779/storageserviceaccountsample-application-reports-keystore-jks-implementation-not)) the issue seems to be related to  GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport().

However, attempting to use AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport() as suggested by the answer on that thread will not work.

I am unable to find the correct import for that class as com.google.api.client.extensions.android.http doesn't seem to be valid.

Here is my code:

```
public static void queryGoogleBooks(JsonFactory jsonFactory, String query) throws Exception {

    //Set up book client
    final Books books = new Books.Builder(GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport(), jsonFactory, null)
            .setApplicationName("Books++")
            .setGoogleClientRequestInitializer(new BooksRequestInitializer(ClientCredentials.API_KEY))
            .build();

    List volumesList = books.volumes().list(query);

    //Execute
    Volumes volumes = volumesList.execute();
    if (volumes.getTotalItems() == 0 || volumes.getItems() == null) {
        System.out.println("No matches found.");
        return;
    }

    // Output results.
    for (Volume volume : volumes.getItems()) {
        Volume.VolumeInfo volumeInfo = volume.getVolumeInfo();
        Volume.SaleInfo saleInfo = volume.getSaleInfo();
        System.out.println("==========");
        // Title.
        System.out.println("Title: " + volumeInfo.getTitle());
        // Author(s).
        java.util.List<String> authors = volumeInfo.getAuthors();
        if (authors != null && !authors.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.print("Author(s): ");
            for (int i = 0; i < authors.size(); ++i) {
                System.out.print(authors.get(i));
                if (i < authors.size() - 1) {
                    System.out.print(", ");
                }
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        // Description (if any).
        if (volumeInfo.getDescription() != null && volumeInfo.getDescription().length() > 0) {
            System.out.println("Description: " + volumeInfo.getDescription());
        }
        // Ratings (if any).
        if (volumeInfo.getRatingsCount() != null && volumeInfo.getRatingsCount() > 0) {
            int fullRating = (int) Math.round(volumeInfo.getAverageRating().doubleValue());
            System.out.print("User Rating: ");
            for (int i = 0; i < fullRating; ++i) {
                System.out.print("*");
            }
            System.out.println(" (" + volumeInfo.getRatingsCount() + " rating(s))");
        }
        // Price (if any).
        if (saleInfo != null && "FOR_SALE".equals(saleInfo.getSaleability())) {
            double save = saleInfo.getListPrice().getAmount() - saleInfo.getRetailPrice().getAmount();
            if (save > 0.0) {
                System.out.print("List: " + CURRENCY_FORMATTER.format(saleInfo.getListPrice().getAmount())
                        + "  ");
            }
            System.out.print("Google eBooks Price: "
                    + CURRENCY_FORMATTER.format(saleInfo.getRetailPrice().getAmount()));
            if (save > 0.0) {
                System.out.print("  You Save: " + CURRENCY_FORMATTER.format(save) + " ("
                        + PERCENT_FORMATTER.format(save / saleInfo.getListPrice().getAmount()) + ")");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        // Access status.
        String accessViewStatus = volume.getAccessInfo().getAccessViewStatus();
        String message = "Additional information about this book is available from Google eBooks at:";
        if ("FULL_PUBLIC_DOMAIN".equals(accessViewStatus)) {
            message = "This public domain book is available for free from Google eBooks at:";
        } else if ("SAMPLE".equals(accessViewStatus)) {
            message = "A preview of this book is available from Google eBooks at:";
        }
        System.out.println(message);
        // Link to Google eBooks.
        System.out.println(volumeInfo.getInfoLink());
    }
    System.out.println("==========");
    System.out.println(
            volumes.getTotalItems() + " total results at http://books.google.com/ebooks?q="
                    + URLEncoder.encode(query, "UTF-8"));
}
```

And the error given:

```
java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: KeyStore JKS implementation not found
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: Not entirely sure why this got a down vote?

Answer (score 0):

Try

replace

`GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport()`

with

`new ApacheHttpTransport()`