# GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport() returning Null

Tags: android, google-api-client, android-httptransport

I'm trying to load Google credential from json file. So before that, I knew, we have to get the default Google transport. [Ref from.](http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=com.google.api.client.googleapis.javanet.GoogleNetHttpTransport) But it always gives `null`. Is anybody faced this issue?

This is my snippet:

```
try {
        JSON_FACTORY =  JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
        HTTP_TRANSPORT = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();

    } catch (Throwable t) {
        Utilities.writeToLogFile(Constants.LOG_ERROR_LEVEL, ".. EXCEPTION" + t.toString());
    }
```

This always ends with `catch` part. says as below

```
... EXCEPTIONjava.security.KeyStoreException: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: KeyStore JKS implementation not found
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [StorageServiceAccountSample application reports "KeyStore JKS implementation not found"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18862779/storageserviceaccountsample-application-reports-keystore-jks-implementation-not)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Finally, I've found an answer on [google issue tracker.](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/robovm/7WYEE5ASpns/nxKmfNoz2lEJ)

Replace

```
HTTP_TRANSPORT = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
```

with

```
HTTP_TRANSPORT = new com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport()
```

But don't know, how it's working.

Comment: It didn't work for me. I had the "SSL protocol exception" with this transport.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use. From Tasks API [sample](https://github.com/google/google-api-java-client-samples/blob/master/tasks-android-sample/src/main/java/com/google/api/services/samples/tasks/android/TasksSample.java) by Google

```
AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport();
```

Comment: This seems to be deprecated!

Comment: it is deprecated but but working for me.