# 'JKS not found' when trying GoogleNetHTTPTransport

Tags: android, keystore, credentials, google-oauth, jks

I've been having some troubles with Google Authorization and I've never worked with any "Google credentials-involved" process before.

My problem takes place after I've created the credential reader (which I assume means that I could access my Google credential's JSON file correctly), just in the line where I instantiate a new Trusted Transport from the `GoogleNetHTTPTransport`. There, the Exception error throws:

```
W/System.err: java.security.KeyStoreException: JKS not found
    at java.security.KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.java:649)
    at com.google.api.client.util.SecurityUtils.getJavaKeyStore(SecurityUtils.java:53)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.GoogleUtils.getCertificateTrustStore(GoogleUtils.java:74)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.javanet.GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport(GoogleNetHttpTransport.java:55)
    at com.example.juans.hasapp.getDataFromSheet.authorize(getDataFromSheet.java:70)
```

I've been investigating but couldn't still find a decent and clear explanation of how these Transports work or why the `KeyStore` is involved in this process.

My code is part of an `AsyncTask` I'm using to fetch data from a Google Sheet, for which I'm currently trying to get access. Here I leave you *authorize()* method that will retrieve me a `Credential` to pass to my `SheetsService`.

```
private Credential authorize(Context context) {
    Resources resources = context.getResources();
    InputStream jsonInput = resources.openRawResource(R.raw.credential_info);
    Reader credentialReader = null;
    try {
        credentialReader = new InputStreamReader(jsonInput);
        Log.v("GoogleAut", "credential reader created");
    } catch (NullPointerException n){
        Log.v("ERROR GoogleAut", "filePath came out empty, no info provided");
    }

    GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets = null;
    try {
        clientSecrets = GoogleClientSecrets
                .load(JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance(),credentialReader);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.v("ERROR GoogleAut","IOException error occurred");
    }

    List<String> scopes = Arrays.asList(SheetsScopes.SPREADSHEETS);

    GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = null;
    try {
        flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow
                .Builder(GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport()
                , JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance()
                ,clientSecrets
                ,scopes)
                .setDataStoreFactory(new MemoryDataStoreFactory())
                .setAccessType("offline")
                .build();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.v("ERROR GoogleAut","IOException error occurred");
    } catch (GeneralSecurityException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.v("ERROR GoogleAut","GeneralSecurityException error occurred");
    }

    try {
        return new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, new LocalServerReceiver())
                .authorize("user");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.v("ERROR GoogleAut", "Unidentified error");
    }
    return null;
}
```

Thanks in advance, I'm just starting with Google developing and I'm very interested in learning about all its possibilities. I also take any suggestions to my coding.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport() returning Null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39248453/googlenethttptransport-newtrustedtransport-returning-null)

Answer (score 36):

Here is answer that helped me solve this issue
https://stackoverflow.com/a/39249969/8853293
You have to replace

```
HTTP_TRANSPORT = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
```

with

```
HTTP_TRANSPORT = new com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport()
```