# KeyStoreException JKS implementation not found using newTrustedTransport method in a not Android app

Tags: java, ibm-midrange, google-sheets-api

I'm writing a small program which exports data from DB2 tables (DB2 for i) to Google Spreadsheet using Google Spreadsheet API. The Java program is called by a CL program in IBM i environment.

I ran the program locally and works fine !!, but when I tried to run the same program was calling by the CL program, I received a KeyStoreException when this line is executed:

**HTTP_TRANSPORT = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();**

The complete exception is:

**java.security.KeyStoreException: KeyStore JKS implementation not found

         at java.security.KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.java:101)

         at com.google.api.client.util.SecurityUtils.getJavaKeyStore(SecurityUtils.java:53)

         at com.google.api.client.googleapis.GoogleUtils.getCertificateTrustStore(GoogleUtils.java:74)

         at com.google.api.client.googleapis.javanet.GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport(GoogleNetHttpTransport.java:55) 
         at prueba.Principal.(Principal.java:48)

         at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initializeImpl(Native Method)

         at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:199)

 Programa Java completado con código de salida 1**

The IBM i's JVM is 1.6 version so perhaps is a version issue, but I built jar file using jdk 1.6.
I built jar file using Gradle.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [StorageServiceAccountSample application reports "KeyStore JKS implementation not found"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18862779/storageserviceaccountsample-application-reports-keystore-jks-implementation-not)

Answer (score 0):

When you say 'ran it locally', do you mean you ran it on your workstation ... or using the JAVA command on IBM i?

If you ran it from your workstation, you may have a keystore entry that the IBM i java doesn't have.

You may want to use a newer version of Java on the i also.  Check out http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=nas8N1011999 for info on what versions of Java are supported on IBM i.

Comment: I ran the application on my workstation, but how can I verified a keystore entry in the IBM i Java ?

Comment: Same as you would in any java install, use the keytool program. You would run it in qshell or qp2term.